# How do I hide a scrollbar with CSS if the content isn't tall enough to scroll?

Tags: css, scrollbar, overflow

If I have a bunch of elements with `overflow-y: scroll`, they will all appear with the `track` of the scrollbar showing up, regardless of whether or not their content is long enough to scroll.

[image]

In this example, only the third item has enough content to scroll down.

How do I make it so that the ones who aren't long enough to scroll don't show the `track`, but the one that **IS** long enough to scroll keeps it?

Codepen example: http://codepen.io/JoshuaSoileau/pen/YwxERp

Answer (score 2):

Set the `overflow-y` to `auto` and it should work like you intend it to work.

```
ul {
      float: left;
      width: 80px;
      list-style: none;
      margin-right: 30px;
      background: rgba(255,0,0,0.25);
      overflow-y: auto;
      max-height: 73px;
    }
```

Comment: Ugh. So simple. Thanks Stefan!